# Error when deploying .NETCore API with Angular Frontend - HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm new to using DevOps and new to the forum. I have been trying to learn Pipelines and CI/CD systems but have been stuck attempting to get a build deployed. Any insights or leads would be much appreciated.

I have a single repository with 3 directories, 1 x .NETCore API, 1 x Angular front end application and 1 with IdentityServer4.

I have a CI pipeline and a CD pipeline that both pass. But I get a HTTP 500.0 error when visiting the domain.

I get the feeling it is something to do with the pipelines that I don't understand properly and have been trying to figure it out. Any thoughts?

**Setup:**
*Azure DevOps, Virtual Machine - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter*

Build YAML:\

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy ARM templates'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: ArmTemplates
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Database File'
  inputs:
    Contents: '**\*.sql'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: UseNode@1
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    checkLatest: true

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    workingDir: 'APP'
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: 'APP'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install -g @angular/cli'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: 'APP'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build --prod'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive APP/dist'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'APP/dist'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dest.zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Release steps:

- Azure resource group deployment
- Azure SQL Database deployment
- IIS web app manage
- IIS web app deploy

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers, Hazzard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember running in to this when .NET core 2 or 3 was rolling out to Azure. After banging my head on it for a long time, the entire issue was around microsofts new hosting module. So, in order to fix it, you need to set the hosting model to out of process.

TL;DR: Add this to your csproj file:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There's quite a few github issues around it:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6111
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21718

Here's the docs around the hosting model:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply mwilson, I applied the recommended fix and no luck initially. But with a bit more tinkering I found I had also forgotten to update the .NETCore to 3.1.x. Much appreciated for your help. I can now stop bashing my head into the wall :P Just to get Ident server 4 to work on a VM with IIS now :)